# Direct link to newsletter - kentico 9

Tags: kentico, newsletter

We are using kentico 9 at work for our website. 
You can subscribe to our newsletter using a "box" which is integrated all the way down on our homepage.
However, I would like to have the opportunity to share a direct subscription link on social media so people can click on it and subscribe to the newsletter.
Now, I have to invite people to go on our website and to go down the page to subscribe which is inconvenient (nobody is going to do this).

I can't find a way to get a direct link (I'm not a developer).
Does anybody know how I could do it ?

Thanks in advance ! :D

Anne

Answer (score 0):

If someone want to subscribe to newsletter, he/she must provide you with email address and I'm not sure that can be done with direct link, because you are not aware of user email address (your target group is unknown group from social media).

You can set up anchor in 'subscribe to newsletter' link, which will automatically scroll down your page to box at the bottom, but I don't think that is the best solution. Maybe, to create a new content page, with only purpose to subscribe users to newsletter (have some introduction text, and widget for 'newsletter' where users can subscribe). I don't know is that what you are looking for, but it is nicer solution then asking people to scroll down and subscribe to newsletter.

Best regards,
Dragoljub

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a specific landing page with that signup form on it.  This way you can have a link you share in social media that takes them directly to that page and allows them to put in their info (first, last and email) and sign up for that specific newsletter.  This way it's a specific call to action on that page and allows for the user to only do one thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think you are right, we'll see :)